# Analytic function bounded away from two simple poles

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having trouble hunting down a solution to an old exam problem.  This is a type of problem I seem to have trouble with, so maybe someone can help me rewire my brain for these.

Suppose $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ \pm 1 \}$ and there exist $a$, $b>0$ such that $$|f(z)| \leq \frac{a}{|z-1|} + \frac{b}{|z+1|}$$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ \pm 1 \}$.  Prove that $$f(z) = \frac{p(z)}{z^2 - 1}$$ where $p$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq 1$.

I sort of see this by noting that $$\lim_{z \to \infty}|f(z)| \leq \lim_{z \to \infty} \frac{a}{|z-1|} + \frac{b}{|z+1|} = 0$$ so that certainly if $f$ has the form indicated, then the numerator must have degree less than 2.  But why this form in the first place?

Comment: hint: try to look at the function $f(z)(z-1)(z+1)$ and first check that it extends to an entire function

Comment: Are you asking for a detailed proof of the statement or motivation behind the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that both $1$ and $-1$ are isolated singularities of $f$ and $0\le\lim_{z\to 1}|(z-1)f(z)|\le a.$ Hence $1$ is a pole of order one or a removable singularity. Same thing happens for $z=-1.$

Let $p(z)=(z^2-1)f(z),$ then $|p(z)|\le (a+b)(|z|+1)$ for all $z\in \Bbb{C}.$

Clearly $p$ is entire and we need to prove that $p$ is a polynomial of the form $Az+B.$

By Cauchy's estimate for all $|z|=R$ and $n\in\Bbb{N},$ we have $$|p^{(n)}(0)|\le n!(a+b)\left(\dfrac{R+1}{R^n}\right)$$ as $R\to\infty$ for all (fixed) $n\ge2,$ we have $p^{(n)}(0)=0.$
Hence the Maclaurin series $$p(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{p^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n$$ gives the required answer.

Comment: All good except, "clearly $p$ is entire.". Why does $f$ need to be differentiable at $\pm 1$?  Can't we have maybe even $f$ is not continuous at $\pm 1$ so that $p$ is not analytic there?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I add few more details to clarify my answer.